# Show the output of PHP function in an alert box called by form="action"

Tags: php, html

Basically, i'm using a `<form action=MyPhp.php>` to upload a file from the client to my server. When the upload is successfull (or not), i send back a message to the client to show the result (success or failed).

Here is the trick : i don't know how to catch that message. If it was only javascript/php i would use XMLHttpRequest(), but i think it can be way easier. I already checked the parameter "onsubmit=" and "target=", but i don't know how to access to the message. My goal would be to show the message as a javascript:alert("The message from php"). Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="Upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="custom-button-style browse-button-style" onclick="Browse()">Browse part</div>
    <input class="toHide" type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" data-role="none"/>
    <input class="toHide" type="submit" value="Upload Part" id="submit" name="submit"  data-role="none"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($imageFileType != "zip" )
{
    echo "The file selected doesn't have the right extension. Please select a .zip file.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($uploadOk == 1)
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $res = $zip->open($target_file);
        if($res == TRUE)
        {
            $zip->extractTo($target_dir);
            $zip->close();
            unlink($target_file);
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} 
?>
```

Comment: actually you can `echo "<script>alert(msg);</script>";` if you do not wish to create an ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you coud try something like this:

```
  echo "<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>";
     echo "alert('your message');";
  echo "</script>";
```

Comment: as far as i can see this shoud be the case.

Comment: I tested it. The message is shown, but it isnt shown on the page where i click the button, but on a blank page (which is my .php). Apparently, it show the message immediatly on the php and isnt return to the html to show it. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Nevermind! I just find out how to do it. I did set the target to a iframe with the css attribut `visibility: hidden;`. It works perfectly!.